# for loop in R variable embedded in string name

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics

I am new to R and am having trouble creating a for loop in which I can use the variable in a string name. For example:

```
lm1 <- lm(a~b+c)
lm2 <- lm(a~b+d)
lm3 <- lm(a~b+e)

for(i in 1:3){
  summary(lm${i})
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Work in a list.

to get your models in a list

```
model_list <- mget(paste0('lm',1:3), envir = parent.frame())
# apply summary on each element of a list
lapply(model_list, summary)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `get` and `paste0`. `paste0` concatenates it's arguments
`get` will fetch the object whose name is defined by string in it's argument

try

```
for(i in 1:3){
  summary(get(paste0('lm',i)))
}
```